# Curve fitting for geo data

Tags: machine-learning, regression, curve-fitting

I recently whipped up a [script](https://github.com/phyous/twitter-geo-data) for capturing large amounts [geo data](https://github.com/phyous/twitter-geo-data/blob/master/data/geo-data-sample.txt) from Twitter's streaming API. I'm looking for some way to create a model to represent the geo "activity" for any given lat/lng point in the world using the data as training input.

I was thinking of rounding all the lat\lng's to two decimal places, and creating a 2-d histogram of all the location occurrences. Thus the input used to train my model would be:

```
x = lat - input
y = lng - input
z = location weight - observed output [normalized between 0.0 and 1.0]
```

I was thinking of creating 24 models (1 for every hour) to model the fact that social network activity is dependent on time of day. This would also simplify things to be 3-d instead of 4-d.

Questions:

- What is the best method for curve fitting the above problem?
- Is there a an existing library I can use to input x,y,z and spit out a best fit
  regression equation? I'm familiar with Ruby, Python, Java or Scala.
  Example code would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused.  What's your independent variable?

Comment: Many of the aspects you bring up are related to [event detection in Twitter](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=event+detection+in+twitter&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C44&as_sdtp=) (see Google Scholar); my bet is you are going to end up modeling the population density of the world (see Figure 1 of [You Are Where You Tweet](http://infolab.cse.tamu.edu/static/papers/cikm1184c-cheng.pdf)), so again, you might want to look into event detection or some other use to do some more interesting things. (P.S., I recently did some Twitter [location related work](https://github.com/bwbaugh/inferhotspot))

Comment: @Gian 'lat' & 'lng' are independent variables producing 'weight'. f(lat,lng) = weight

Comment: @WesleyBaugh you're on to something with event detection. I'm trying to build a real time event detection visualizer. An event being defined as a sudden surge in activity that is unaccounted for in historical data. I want to apply the above model to incoming tweets so that I can weight them higher/lower on a heatmap. I came across [pyeq2](https://code.google.com/p/pyeq2/downloads/detail?name=pyeq2_8.3.zip&can=2&q=), will update if anything comes of it.

Answer (score 1):

The [K-Means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) algorithm might help here.  It could be used to work out where clusters of tweets are, given the lat and lng of all the tweets.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question? Clustering assigns points to a, well, cluster. The OP is trying to do some form of regression related to the *number* of tweets in a geographic area. Maybe I'm missing an obvious connection.

Comment: (Though, I do think clustering might play a part in the overall solution, however, clustering doesn't seem to be enough here on its own.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I would take. You should be building a regression model, with at least the following predictors: latitude, longitude, population density at (lat,long), time (probably categorical), and any other relevant features. You're regressing against some measure of activity.

I can help you as far as python libraries go: if you want to build a standard linear model (probably not, but you can use it as a starting point), [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/generated/example_ols.html) is a good place to start. You can at least get MSE on some test data.

Given the model is likely to be complex and there will be many interactions, you might want to compare this to something like a neural net regression model---if so, [pybrain](http://pybrain.org/) is very simple to set up to do this kind of thing.